# Conflicts between multiple gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, insert

I have multiple gridviews on one page. For each gridview, there are two ways to insert a new record. One is through FooterTemplate of a TemplateField when the gridview has data and the other through EmptyDataTemplate when the gridview is empty.

By itself, the inserts work well. However, if another gridview is empty, then by default, the insert portion in its EmptyDataTemplate is displayed. When this is displayed, I can't get the FooterTemplate of another gridview to display. That portion is inaccessible until I get rid of the EmptyDataTemplate by forcing an insert.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewDomSoilType" runat="server" Text="Add new record"  CssClass="btnNewRecord" OnClick="addNewDomSoilType" />              
<asp:GridView ID="gvDomSoilType" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsDomSoilType" CssClass="data" 
AllowSorting="True" onrowcommand="gvDomSoilType_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="HabitatObsSubstrateID, HabitatObservationID, SubstrateID" >
    <Columns>                        
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">                            
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
                AlternateText="Delete" ForeColor="Blue"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsertSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandName="SubmitInsert" CssClass="btnInsertSEID" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsertCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="CancelInsert" CssClass="btnInsertSEID" CausesValidation="false" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                        
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Substrate" SortExpression="Substrate">
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSoilType" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="dsDomSoilType_Insert" DataTextField="Description" 
                DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>                          
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Substrate") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Substrate: " CssClass="insertLabel"></asp:Label> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSoilType2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="dsDomSoilType_Insert" DataTextField="Description" 
        DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnInsertEmpty" runat="Server" Text="Insert" CommandName="EmptyInsert" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>    

<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewVegCover" runat="server" Text="Add new record"  CssClass="btnNewRecord" OnClick="addNewVegCover" />
<asp:GridView ID="gvVegCover" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsVegCover" CssClass="data" 
AllowSorting="True" onrowcommand="gvVegCover_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="HabitatObsVegID">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">                           
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
                AlternateText="Delete" ForeColor="Blue"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsertSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandName="SubmitInsert" CssClass="btnInsertSEID" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsertCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="CancelInsert" CssClass="btnInsertSEID" CausesValidation="false" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HabitatVegetationType" SortExpression="HabitatVegetationType">                            
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVegType" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="dsVegType_Insert" DataTextField="Description" 
                DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>                                 
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblVegType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HabitatVegetationType") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VegetationTypePercent" SortExpression="VegetationTypePercent">                            
        <FooterTemplate>                                    
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVegTypePercent" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>               
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblVegTypePercentage" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VegetationTypePercent") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                                                     
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Vegetation Type:" CssClass="insertLabel"></asp:Label>  
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVegType2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="dsVegType_Insert" DataTextField="Description" 
        DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Percenttage:" CssClass="insertLabel"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtVegTypePercent2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>      
    <asp:Button ID="btnInsertEmpty" runat="Server" Text="Insert" CommandName="EmptyInsert" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>        
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void addNewDomSoilType(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvDomSoilType.ShowFooter = true;
    }

    protected void addNewVegCover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvVegCover.ShowFooter = true;
    }
```

I know my explanation is a bit confusing. Let me know what doesn't make sense and I'll try to clarify. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

These two gridviews shouldn't impact each other. I think it might be the PostBack that is messing up the state of the webpage. On the PageLoad do Page.IsPostBack false and then populate the data. Make sure the events are hooked up to the right GridView.

Comment: These controls also have a few validations. Could those be messing with it?

Comment: Turns out, it was the validations messing up the form submits. Fixed the issue by putting CausesValidation="false" in some places. Thanks for looking everyone.